# Can not build react apps from npm

Tags: reactjs

I have an react js application.I am trying to build this apps from "npm run build" but it take long time to build and its failed.please check below log error and advise where it is problem.

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~prebuild: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
6 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
7 verbose lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Node JS and REact\Source Code\KHAdmin\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;c:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Users\Junaid\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Junaid\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: CWD: D:\Node JS and REact\Source Code\KHAdmin
10 silly lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts build' ]
11 silly lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 build: `react-scripts build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:310:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
15 verbose cwd D:\Node JS and REact\Source Code\KHAdmin
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.16.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 build: `react-scripts build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete node_modules folder and run `npm install`, after that try to build again